# Wicket implement flash redirection

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I would like to perform something like a flash redirection (not sure if it is really called flash redirection).

After a certain action like delete device, I am redirecting to the device list page.

Now, for the redirect URL... I am appending `&sdr=true` and it works.

The problem is... that parameter (`&sdr=true`) stays there even after just refreshing the page.

If I remember it correctly, when I do flash refresh... the parameter stays there but will disappear on refresh... or just good for one refresh only.

Below is my method for redirection:

```
public static void redirect(String redirectUrl) {
    throw new RedirectToUrlException(redirectUrl);
}
```

now, how do I implement the flash redirection in wicket? I am using wicket 6 version.

Or... I would like the parameter `&sdr=true` be good only for 1 request. When the page is refreshed or reloaded... it should be gone.

Thanks :)

Sorry if this question is very easy, I am really new to wicket

Answer (score 1):

May be there is another solution for your problem.

Wicket could be stateful, i.e. it can keep state between the pages navigation. So you can do:

```
setResponsePage(new SomePage(someState));
```

this way there is no need to pass anything in the url and SomePage's constructor can decide what to do with the passed state.

If you prefer to add request parameter in the url then you may use

```
PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
params.put("sdr", "true");
setResponsePage(SomePage.class, params);
```

In SomePage's constructor you will need to remove the `sdr` parameter from the passed PageParameters so that it is not rendered in all urls inside the page, e.g. in links, form action, etc.
But if you want the parameter to disappear in a page refresh/reload then you will need to make another redirect:

```
public SomePage(PageParameters params) {
   super(params);

   StringValue srdValue = params.get("srd");
   if (!srdValue.isNull()) {
      params.remove("srd");

      // do something custom

      throw new RestartResponseException(this);
      // or throw new RestartResponseException(getPageClass(), params);
   }


}
```